# MySql join with 2 Tables and 2 join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables:

```
posts: userid, lastuserid
users: id, name
```

I need to join `posts.userid = users.id` and `posts.lastuserid = users.id` to get `username` and `lastusername`.

My query did as below:

```
SELECT posts. * , users.name, vUsers.name
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.userid
INNER JOIN Users ON vUsers.id = posts.lastuserid
```

Is there any other (better) way to do this?

Comment: If your query works, then this is the right way to do it.  (The query in the question won't work, but I suspect that is a copying error.)

Comment: Can u please provide sample data n expected data?

Comment: `vUsers`? what is that? and your table name `users` uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: @gordon, yes the query is work.

Comment: @shaiful islam, vUsers is view of exact users table, that I need to create this query. I wonder if query can be built without need of this vUsers.

Comment: then you used tablename wrong. it should be `INNER JOIN vUsers ON vUsers.id = posts.lastuserid`

Comment: also you need to use select statement like this `SELECT posts. * , users.name AS uname, vUsers.name AS vuname` because both table has name column and you need to use alias.You can do alias one if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is probably correct.  I would encourage you to use table aliases that are abbreviations for the things you are looking for:

```
SELECT p. * , u.name as username, l.name as lastusername
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = p.userid INNER JOIN
     users l
     ON l.id = p.lastuserid;
```

Your query has something called `vUsers`, which is not defined.

Comment: vUsers is exact view of users. Using alias, you negate the need of vUsers. Thank you